# Are negative effects from faith cards permanent?

Tags: shadow-empire

In Shadow empire it is possible to play a negative faith card to gain some faith points in exchange for a negative effect. Are these effects permanent or do they diminish over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, effects of faith cards are a one time change to the settlements stats, and they will diminish over time like regular changes to those stats.